# There is an error in my Pine script code (Undeclared identifier 'input') & (No value assigned to the `defval` parameter)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Help me correct the issue in the pine script version 5

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Mailbin

//@version=5
indicator("Free Float", overlay=true)
shares_outstanding = input.float(title="Shares Outstanding", type=input.float)
shares_available_for_trading = input.float(title="Shares Available for Trading", type=input.float)
free_float = (shares_available_for_trading / shares_outstanding) * 100
plot(free_float, title="Free Float", color= color.green, linewidth=2)
```

Following are the errors

```
Error at 6:67 Undeclared identifier 'input'
Error at 6:22 No value assigned to the `defval` parameter
Error at 7:32 No value assigned to the `defval` parameter
```

I tried to plot the indicator showing the free float of the stock in the main chart.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are pretty clear.

You need to assing a default value to your inputs by using the `defval` argument.

Secondly, in `v5`, there is no argument like `type` in `input.x()` functions. So, you need to remove that.

```
shares_outstanding = input.float(1.0, title="Shares Outstanding")
shares_available_for_trading = input.float(2.0, title="Shares Available for Trading")
```